# Use Fn.conditionIf to return Object instead of String in AWS CDK

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I wanted to do something like below:

```
ElasticsearchClusterConfigProperty property = Fn.conditionIf(useProdConfigCondition.getLogicalId(), ElasticsearchClusterConfigProperty.builder()
        .instanceCount(10)
        .instanceType("m5.large.elasticsearch")
        .dedicatedMasterEnabled(true)
        .dedicatedMasterCount(3)
        .dedicatedMasterType("c5.large.elasticsearch")
        .zoneAwarenessEnabled(true)
        .zoneAwarenessConfig(CfnDomain.ZoneAwarenessConfigProperty.builder()
                .availabilityZoneCount(2)
                .build())
        .build(),
ElasticsearchClusterConfigProperty.builder()
        .instanceCount(2)
        .instanceType("m5.large.elasticsearch")
        .dedicatedMasterEnabled(false)
        .dedicatedMasterCount(3)
        .build()
);
```

i.e. Select elasticsearchConfigProperty based on the condition. Is there any way to do this? With Fn.IfCondition, we can return a string, but not the object.

Comment: CDK is like a programming language, just use a simple if

Comment: @AmitBaranes not if you want the logic to be present in the CloudFormation template